# Are Haar measures localizable?

Tags: measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

I'm trying to prove that Haar measures are localizable. we know that Haar measures are decomposable ( see [Haar measures are decomposable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4663850/1034911)) in the sense that:

A measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ is *decomposable* if:

> (i) $X$ is a disjoint union of measurable subsets, $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_{i}$, with $\mu(X_{i})<\infty$ for all $i$.

> (ii) $\mu(E)=\sum_{i\in I}\mu(E\cap X_i)$ for every measurable set $E$ of finite measure.

> (iii) if $E\subseteq X$ and $E\cap X_i\in \frak{M}$ for all $i$, then $E\in\frak{M}$.

if relation (ii) holds for every $E\in \frak{M}$, then we called  $(X,\frak{M},\mu)$ localizable.

> $\color{blue}{\textbf{can someone tell me that is my solution correct or not?}}$

$\color{green}{\textbf{my solution:}}$

$\color{red}{\textbf{the idea of proof is to prove that:}}$

> $\color{red}{\bigg[}$there exists a measure $\lambda$ on ${\frak{B}}_G$ that is radon and translation invariant and hence is a Haar measure on $G$ and by uniqueness of haar measure, we prove that the first Haar measure $\mu$ is equal with this new measure $\lambda$ and finally, the measure $\lambda$ have a property that localizability is proved.$\color{red}{\bigg]}$

if $G$ be a locally compact group  and $(G,{\frak{B}}_G,\mu)$ be Haar measure space where ${\frak{B}}_G$ is the borel $\sigma$-algebra, then if we define a measure $\lambda$ on ${\frak{B}}_G$ such that:

\begin{equation}
    \lambda(E)=
    \begin{cases}
      \underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i) & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)<\infty \\
      \infty & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=\infty
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

$\color{red}{\textbf{proof that $\lambda$ is a translation invariant measure:}}$

if $\{E_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of disjoint measurable sets, then if $\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\bigg(\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}E_j\bigg)\bigcap X_i\bigg]<\infty$, then $\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E_j\cap X_i)<\infty$ for every $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and  we have

$\lambda\bigg(\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}E_j\bigg)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\bigg(\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}E_j\bigg)\bigcap X_i\bigg]=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\underset{j\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}\bigg(E_j\bigcap X_i\bigg)\bigg]=\underset{i \in I}{\sum}\underset{j\in \mathbb{N}}{\sum}\mu(E_j\cap X_i)\color{red}=\underset{j\in \mathbb{N}}{\sum}\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E_j\cap X_i)=\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\lambda(E_j)$

equality in red follows from following relation in measure theory. if we consider $\mu$ as counting measure and $X$ as arbitrary set.

$$\int_X\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}f_j(x)d\mu=\underset{j\in \mathbb{N}}{\sum}\int_Xf_j(x)d\mu$$

now if $\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\bigg(\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}E_j\bigg)\bigcap X_i\bigg]=\infty$, then we have $\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\sum}\lambda(E_j)=\infty$ and
$\lambda\bigg(\underset{j\in\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}E_j\bigg)=\infty$.
also it is trivial that $\mu(\phi)=0$ and is proved that $\lambda$ is really a measure on ${\frak{B}}_G$.

it is easy to see that $\lambda$ is translation invariant.

we have to prove that the measure $\lambda$ is radon.

$\color{red}{\textbf{proof that $\lambda$ is finite on compact sets:}}$

if $K\in {\frak{B}}_G$ is a compact set, then $\mu(K)<\infty$ and by property (ii) of decomposability, it follows that $\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(K\cap X_i)=\mu(K)<\infty$. hence $\lambda(K)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(K\cap X_i)<\infty$ and $\lambda$ is finite on compact sets.

$\color{red}{\textbf{proof that $\lambda$ is inner regular on sets of finite measure:}}$

if $E\in{\frak{B}}_G$ and $\lambda(E)<\infty$ and for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, then

$\lambda(E)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)$

and by definition, there exists a finite set $F\subseteq I$ suchthat

$\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\underset{i\in F}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)$

now since $\mu\bigg[\underset{i\in F}{\bigcup}(E\cap X_i)\bigg]<\mu(E)<\infty$, then there exists a compact set $K\subseteq \underset{i\in F}{\bigcup}(E\cap X_i)\subseteq E$ such that

$$\mu\bigg[\underset{i\in F}{\bigcup}(E\cap X_i)\bigg]-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\mu(K)$$

and it follows that:

$\lambda(E)-\epsilon=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)-\epsilon<\underset{i\in F}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)-\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\mu\bigg[\underset{i\in F}{\bigcup}(E\cap X_i)\bigg]-\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\mu(K)$

hence we have

$$ \lambda(E)-\epsilon<\mu(K) $$

where $K\subseteq E$. hence
inner regularity on sets with finite measure is proved.

$\color{red}{\textbf{proof that $\lambda$ is outer regular}}$

if $E\in {\frak{B}}_G$ with $\lambda(E)=\infty$. then since $\lambda$ is a measure and $E\subseteq G$, then we have $\lambda(G)=\infty$ and since $G$ is open, then $\lambda$ is inner regular on sets with infinite measure.

now if $E\in {\frak{B}}_G$ and $\lambda(E)<\infty$ and for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, since $\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=\lambda(E)<\infty$, then $\mu(E\cap X_i)=0$ except for countable number  of $i\in \mathbb{N}\subseteq I$. hence we have

$$\lambda(E)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=\underset{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]$$

now, there exists an open set $O_1\supseteq \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]$ such that $\mu(O_1)<\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]+\epsilon$

and it follows that

$$\mu(O_1)<\lambda(E)+\epsilon\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$

now, there exists a compct set $K\subseteq \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]$ such that

$$\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\mu(K)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$

> but in the case of Haar measure, the set $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ is equal with $\{gU'_n|g\in C, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and  $H=\underset{n\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}U'_n$ where $H$ is a open subgroup of $G$ and the set $C$ contains one poin from every coset $gH$ (for details, see [Haar measures are decomposable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4663850/1034911)).
> know if $K\subseteq G$ be a compact set, then since $K\subseteq \underset{g\in C}{\bigcup}gH$ and $\{gH|g\in C\}$ is an open cover of $K$, then since $K$ is compact, there exists a finite set $g_1,...,g_n$ such that $K\subseteq \underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\bigcup}}g_iH$.
> hence $K$ is subset of union of countable numbers of $X_i$  $\Bigg(K\subseteq \underset{i\in \mathbb{N'}}{\bigcup}X_i\Bigg)$ where $\mathbb{N'}$ is a countable subset of $I$.

now we have

$$K\subseteq \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]\bigcap\bigg[\underset{i\in \mathbb{N'}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg]=\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in\mathbb{N''}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]$$

where $\mathbb{N''}\subseteq I\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is a countable subset of $I$ and we have

$$\mu(K)\leq\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in\mathbb{N''}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]=\underset{i\in \mathbb{N''}}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=0$$

because we know that if $i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}$, then $\mu(E\cap X_i)=0$.

hence $\mu(K)=0$ and from formula $(2)$, we have  $\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\mu(K)=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

also there exists an open set $O_2\supseteq \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]$ such that $\mu(O_2)<\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$

hence we have

$$\mu(O_2)<\mu\bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]+\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(3)$$

and by formula $(1)$ and $(3)$, we have

$$\mu(O_1\cup O_2)\leq\mu(O_1)+\mu(O_2)<[\lambda(E)+\epsilon]+\epsilon=\lambda(E)+2\epsilon$$

where $E\subseteq \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in \mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]\bigcup \bigg[E\bigcap\bigg(\underset{i\in I\setminus\mathbb{N}}{\bigcup}X_i\bigg)\bigg]\subseteq O_1\cup O_2$.

but since $\lambda(E)<\infty$, then $\mu(O_1\cup O_2)<\infty$ and by second decomposability property of Haar measure, we have

$$\infty>\mu(O_1\cup O_2)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\bigg(O_1\cup O_2\bigg)\cap X_i\bigg]$$

hence by definition of $\lambda$, it follows that

$$\lambda(O_1\cup O_2)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu\bigg[\bigg(O_1\cup O_2\bigg)\cap X_i\bigg]=\mu(O_1\cup O_2)<\lambda(E)+2\epsilon$$

hence we have

$$ \lambda(O_1\cup O_2)<\lambda(E)+2\epsilon $$

where $E\subseteq O_1\cup O_2$. and is proved that $\lambda$ is outer regular.

$\color{red}{\textbf{proof that $\mu$ is localizable}}$

now by uniqueness of Haar measure, we know that $\lambda=\mu$ and we have:

\begin{equation}
    \mu(E)=\lambda(E)=
    \begin{cases}
      \underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i) & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)<\infty \\
      \infty & \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)=\infty
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

and it follows that in any case we have

$\mu(E)=\underset{i\in I}{\sum}\mu(E\cap X_i)$

and second decomposability property of Haar measure  holds for every $E\in {\frak{B}}_G$ and it follows that Haar measure $\mu$ is localizable.

Comment: Do not put "EDITED" in your title, nor exclamation marks. This is silly and hurts readability/searchability. Titles aren't meant to alert the reader to the content, not to serve as advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

I did not check your proof, but Haar measures are not localizable in the sense that you define (some authors call this "strictly localizable" instead).

Indeed, as established in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800760/why-every-localizable-measure-space-is-semifinite-measure-space), we need a semi-finite measure for a localizable space. Yet, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663622/are-haar-measures-semifinite/4676140#4676140) it is shown that Haar measure need not be semi-finite.